# Getting 'PERFORMANCE WARNING' messages in Chrome

Tags: webgl, three.js

I just recently starting getting these messages, and was wondering if anyone has seen them, or know what may be causing them.  I'm using Three.js with Chrome version '21.0.1180.57' on MacOS.  I don't get these messages with Safari or FireFox.

> PERFORMANCE WARNING: Attribute 0 is disabled. This has signficant performance penalty
>
> WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.

Answer (score 3):

Same message on Firefox is : "Error: WebGL: Drawing without vertex attrib 0 array enabled forces the browser to do expensive emulation work when running on desktop OpenGL platforms, for example on Mac. It is preferable to always draw with vertex attrib 0 array enabled, by using bindAttribLocation to bind some always-used attribute to location 0."

This is not only a performance drawback, but will also result in bad output.

**PROBLEM**: This message occurs if a JS tries to run a WebGL shader that is expecting color information in gl_Color on a mesh not providing a color array.

**SOLUTION**: Use a WebGL shader with constant color not accessing gl_Color or provide a color array in the mesh to be shaded.

If using lightgl.js from Evan Wallace, try to add the option `colors:true` in the `new GL.Mesh` statement and provide a propper `mesh.colors` array of same size as your `vertices` array. Or try this shader:

```
blackShader = new GL.Shader(
  'void main() { gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex; }',
  'void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); }'
);
```

*Sorry, I never used Three.js but the problem should be similar, provide color to your mesh before shading.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Chrome bug:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium-os/issues/detail?id=32528

Comment: Yes, I saw that too.  The weird thing is that when things are first rendered, everything works just fine.  Later when other elements are added, I start getting the warnings.  I was hoping someone had the same issue and knew what specifically was causing it.  I was trying to avoid checking for the warnings after each element I add to the scene.  I'll try it, and report what I find.

Comment: I thought I had already tried removing all cylinders based on another link I found, but apparently not correctly.  I've discovered that the only element that I'm currently using that causes this, is a cylinder.  I guess I'll wait to see if it's fixed in a future update of Chrome, or if there's another element I can use.  The whole point of using a cylinder was to detect collisions on a sprite.  I couldn't intersect a sprite with a ray, so I surrounded the sprite with an invisible cylinder...