# WebGL not rendering may be related to warning

Tags: webgl

I am rather new to OpenGL and trying to learn a little WebGl. I came across [a tutorial](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28) that, while great, appears to be a bit dated. I implemented my own version of this [example in a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/f00X1QMRWXhJjO2xcVHz). I left out the square on purpose, however, once I have everything wired I do not see the triangle. I found a warning in the console...

```
WARNING: Attribute 0 is disabled. This has signficant performance penalty
```

And there is another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305231/webgl-warning-attribute-0-is-disabled-this-has-significant-performance-penalt) that seems to be similar but looking through the diff I can't get it to work and I can't get what he is saying to click. Here is my drawing code for reference...

```
drawScene() {
    this.gl.viewport(0, 0, this.gl.viewportWidth, this.gl.viewportHeight);
    this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    mat4.perspective(45, this.gl.viewportWidth / this.gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, this.pMatrix);
    mat4.identity(this.mvMatrix);
    mat4.translate(this.mvMatrix, this.mvMatrix, [-1.5, 0.0, -7.0]);
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, this.triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    this.setMatrixUniforms();
    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
  }
```

Does anyone have experiance here that can help guide a newbie?

Comment: [these tutorials might help too](http://webglfundamentals.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So going back through [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context) helped a lot. One thing to consider is it doesn't talk about the glUtils js file they import so yeah that is needed. It seems that what the warning message is referring to is the need in newer versions to be explicit about params for the shader. Here is an [example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hJvRddNCnluhQszz8uR0?p=preview) you will notice this is different...

```
// NEEDED to prevent warning
    this.vertexPositionAttribute = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vertexPositionAttribute);
```

When I set my shader attributes this way I avoid the warning!